# How to close app when running on background after a while?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I use Flutter and want to automatically close my app when it runs in the background (not turned off completely, still displayed in the multitasking window) for more than 3 minutes. Does anyone have a solution?

On iOS, I use the code below. However, when I open the app after 3 minutes, it automatically turns off, and I have to reopen the app again.

```
   _listener = AppLifecycleListener(
      onHide: () {
        _timer = Timer(const Duration(minutes: 3), () {
          FlutterExitApp.exitApp(iosForceExit: true);
        });
      
      },
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can't do this. Because timers don't run while your app is suspended, when you bring your app to the foreground the timer then fires and your app exits.

Comment: As Paul said, it would be useful to know why you want to do this. Do you just want to make sure the screen snapshot for your app in the task switcher doesn’t contain any private information? We generally just obscure that information when the app goes into background. Or are you worried about the memory consumption? The OS will take care of that for, merely suspending it if it can, but will automatically jettison (i.e., terminate) it for you when it needs. But as a general rule, we never manually terminate iOS apps programmatically.

Comment: Regarding the basic lifecycle, see [Managing your app’s life cycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle). Also see [Choosing Background Strategies for Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/choosing-background-strategies-for-your-app).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.